# How to make a html node visible to an Angular controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Our angular web app has sevaral panels. Each panel has header made of header text and close button and content as shown on the image below.

[image: Panel]

The code which implements it has approximately the following structure:

```
<aside class="right-panel" ng-controller="panelsController">
<header>
    <button type="button"><i class="close"></i></button>
    <h2>{{currentPanelCaption}}</h2>
</header>
<div class="scrollable-y">
    <div ng-show="panels.panelA" ng-controller="ctrlA">
        <panel-a-directive></panel-a-directive>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="panels.panelB" ng-controller="ctrlB">
        <panel-b-directive></panel-b-directive>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="panels.panelC" ng-controller="ctrlC">
        <panel-c-directive></panel-c-directive>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="panels.panelD">
        <div ng-include src="'Partials/some_simple.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</aside>
```

But now some panels require to inject some additional custom controls to the header. For example, this new button should be visible only for panel C.

[image]

The question is how to make header extendable? Is there a proper way how to embed a piece of html into header and make it available for a particular controller, e.g. Controller C. I don't want to place handlers for `Some Button` inside `$rootScope`.

Comment: Make it (the header) a directive and pass in what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your concerns are valid. What you'll want to do is define where/how this new functionality should be used. Is this "button" going to be reusable and inserted in multiple places? Is this going to be used just for controller C?

If you expect to use the "button" in multiple places then you can put the handler for the button inside of the directive itself, and then inject any dependencies that it might need.

```
angular.directive('yourDirective', ['requiredService', 'requiredFactory', 'requiredFilter', 
 function (requiredService, requiredFactory, requiredFilter) {
    return {
        //...
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
             element.bind('click', function(){
             //your event handler
             }
        }
    }
}])
```

otherwise simply put your logic in the controller that you might want to have the handling logic. You would do that by appending editing the scope for your directive to pass the handler into it and then handle it in the constructor:

```
angular.directive('yourDirective', ['requiredService', 'requiredFactory', 'requiredFilter', 
 function (requiredService, requiredFactory, requiredFilter) {
    return {
        scope:{
          eventHandler:'&'
        },
        template: '.... ng-click="eventHandler()"....'
    }
}])
```

then in your HTML do

```
<your-directive event-handler="eventHandler" />
```

and in your controller do

```
scope.eventHandler = function(){
 .... your stuff ....
}
```

Comment: The button is only controller C specific. But how do I get control over the element which is out of controller C scope?

Comment: Updated on how to pass a function to the directive. You'll want to look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive  to get a clear understanding of what you're doing here